# scheduling files for upload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to schedule the files for upload. Files are residing in companies network(on intranet)

I use "FileUpload" to browse the files on screen which are scheduled for upload. But the FileUpload does not give the full path of the file. So what is the way to workaround this limitation.

Comment: You want to get the path of the file on the client machine from a fileupload? that's not possible for security reasons. Though, I do remember that It's possible in either IE or FF with some javascript.

Comment: exactly...  I want the path of file on client machine. because I want to upload it later, not when its selected on UI.

Comment: You should move the value of selected file in cache or temporary variable if size is not much greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for security reasons. Though, I It's possible in either IE with some javascript